# touch(): Unable to create file writable absolute

Tags: php

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

> Message: touch(): Unable to create file writable absolute path\ci_session4b3f8517c6bb7e9f0bf60076212ed2f2b0af9011 because No such file or directory

Filename: `drivers/Session_files_driver.php`

Line Number: `234`

Backtrace:

Comment: Do you have a question for the community? Or do you have a fetish for PHP errors you want to share with us?

Answer (score 0):

«No such file or directory» is the answer: check your path (for example dots, slashes)